# How to unit test a facebook user?

Tags: python, facebook, unit-testing

I have created a test user on my facebook app.

I can access the test user as explained [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/test-users#managetool)

In fact via POSTMAN in Chrome I can easily access it with this url and get a 200 response.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.1/xxxxxx/accounts/test-users?access_token=yyyyyyy
```

However the same url doesn't work in my unit test. I get a 404 for `rv`
What am I overlooking please?

```
class TestFBConnectAPI(BaseTest):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TestFBConnectAPI, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def test_connect_signup(self):
        app_access_token = facebook.get_app_access_token(app.config['FB_CLIENT_ID'],
                                                         app.config['FB_CLIENT_SECRET'])

        rv = self.client.post('https://graph.facebook.com/v2.1/{0}/accounts/test-users?access_token={1}'.format(app.config['FB_CLIENT_ID'], app_access_token))
        self.assertTrue(rv.status_code, 200)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Test client](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/testing/tools/#the-test-client) is for GET/POST simulation for the django views you're developing, not for the external service.

You need to use modules/libraries like [`urllib`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html), [`requests`](http://python-requests.org/), ... if you want to interact with external services.

```
import requests

....

url = ('https://graph.facebook.com/v2.1/{0}/'
       'accounts/test-users?access_token={1}'.format(app.config['FB_CLIENT_ID'],
                                                     app_access_token))
response = requests.post(url)
self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```